# css "window" to z-index

Tags: css, z-index, tunnel

I'm creating a website, where I put a menubar on top of a background image.

The menubar is build as `<nav><div><ul><li>[<ul>]</li></div></nav>`.

The div element owns a background. `li-tags` own a background depending on selection and hover.

When hovering over a menu item, I actually want it to be transparent, so that you can see the background image through the parent-tags. However the div needs a background for having a bar.

Is there a possibility to build a kind of tunnel through the parents to a specific `z-index` or to set only the corresponding background of the parent transparent? Something like `backgroundZ: -5`

Comment: There is no z-index solution. Just don't give the `div` a background. Give each of the menus the background.

Comment: The <div> needs a background because the menu also contains space without items. The menubar uses the whole width while the items just use as much space as they need.
Is there a solution with jquery or sth. else, to make only a certain part of the div transparent?

Comment: I think there is, yes, but you should post the code first.